# How do I detect traps?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

One of my party members just got killed by a trap. Having reloaded, I'd rather not have the same thing happen again.

How do I actually detect and disable the traps though?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be in scouting mode to detect traps (Alt, or click on the third icon from the left in the bottom row). As far as I understand you also need to have a character with sufficient mechanics skill to detect the specific trap.

Once you detected the trap, select a character with sufficient mechanics skill and just click on the trap to disarm it.

Comment: There are sometimes issues with clicking on the trap if you have multiple party members selected, a good way to ensure that they will actually try to disarm it: (1) the cursor should turn into a bear trap icon and (2) *only one* member should walk over to the trap. if your whole party is moving, hit pause before everyone gets blown away. It's also a good idea to have the rest of the party stand back in case the disarm fails and the trap goes off

Comment: Mechanics Skill is for searching/detecting traps and hidden objects, not Perception.